# Cached images in chrome at refreshing the page. load() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've made a simple page with html, css and javascript (and jQuery). The page is in develop and has a few simple lines of code:

[this is the page](http://testdebian.com.ar/alejandro/jokeCreator/viewer/2.1/index.php)

The thing is when refreshing the page several times in chrome, sometimes Chrome loads the javascript and other it doesn't. This happens only when refreshing several times, not at the first load.

This happens only in Chrome and it works very well on any other browser.

Why? Anyone with the same problem? 
thanks for your time.

Problem found: The problem was in cached images with the jQuery method load(). I've tried the paulirish [plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded), but it seems to do the same thing randomly when refreshing. My code for this is:

```
    $(img)
    .attr({
        //src:'http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/331360_2681959258277_1535210086_2696160_1853452662_o.jpg',
        src:'http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/425947_331598576876081_246781332024473_794518_640826950_n.jpg',
        id: 'bigPic'
    })
    .appendTo('#bigPicWrap')
    .imagesLoaded(function () {
        //some code with the image accessing it with: $(this)
    });
```

Maybe something wrong in the code? Bad use of the plugin? this is still happening only on chrome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i actually used to have the problem. i think the problem was that i was trying to load a script file in a script tag, that was linked to somewhere else (as in another site), and it was failing to load the file, and causing other JS to cease in executing properly

Comment: Kristian all the scrpts calls are locals. I made the times that this happens to decrease by adding a string at the end of the script call: '<script src="/js/MyFile.js?<?=time()?>"></script>'. But it still does the same when refreshing some times. Realy I don't  understand what cause this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set ajax to not cache responses

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```